# How do I use a function inside another function and make operations with it in Python?

Tags: python

I'm wondering, how could I use a function that I've already defined inside another function? For example, I have a function `f(n)`. Then I want to create a function `g(n)` such that it returns `f(n)*2`.

I'm trying to learn Python and I already know how to use some basic functions, then I tried to make a program to calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers. I created that function. I called it `gcd(a,b)`, and it returns the GCD of `a` and `b`. It worked very well!

Then I want to reuse this function to calculate the Least Common Multiple of `a` and `b`.

I used the following code:

```py
def lcm(a,b):
    u=gcd(a,b)
    v=a*b/u
    print(v)
```

Using the fact that `lcm(a,b)*gcd(a,b)=a*b` I expect, with this code, that the output to be the LCM of `a` and `b`. But when I run the code and use the defined function I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    lcm(2,2)
  File "C:/Users/(my user name)/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/euclides.py", line 55, in lcm
    v=a*b/u
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

What does it means and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the TypeError suggests, the error comes from the `v=a*b/u` line where `u` is **supposed** to be the return value from `gcd()`.

It seems that the function `gcd()` is not returning any value. You need to add `return` from the `gcd()` function which you haven't included. As a pseudo code, do something like

```
def gcd(a, b):
    # var = Do some stuff
    return var

def lcm(a,b):
    u=gcd(a,b)
    v=a*b/u
    return v

a = # some value
b = # some value
print (lcm(a, b))
```

Comment: I revised my code and indeed I forgot to use the Return function. Then the function was only printing things instead of evaluating the operations. I changed it and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change it to *return* the result rather than just print it:

```
def lcm(a,b):
    u=gcd(a,b)
    v=a*b/u
    return v
```

Without the `return`, it will print the result, then implicitly return `None`.

You need to make the same change to your `gcd` function in order for the call to work as intended (it looks like your `gcd` function is returning `None`).  Also note that in Python 3, `gcd` is available as `math.gcd`.

Comment: I found a problem with my code. I was misusing the print and return functions. I changed it and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different structure also:

```
class GCD_model:
    def gcd(a, b):
        # var = Do some stuff
        return var

def lcm(a,b, model):
    u=model.gcd(a,b)
    v=a*b/u
    return v

a = # some value
b = # some value
model = GCD_model()
print (lcm(a, b, model))
```